# Access: Forms, Subforms and Queries

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

According to the searching I've done over the past couple of days, what I'm trying to achieve should be fairly straightforward but nothing that I've found has solved my problems.  This is my first time at using Access, or SQL at all.  Apologies in advance for the length of the question.

Essentially I need to pick up a value from one table and multiply it by another in the another table, and then store the result in the second table, via forms and subforms.

**The Problem:**

I'm attempting to create a database of projects, part of which is a quotation tool.  The database has several tables covering all the required inputs for our project managers, most of which are linked to the PKs of their parent tables.

My current attempt has a form (`frmJobDetails`) giving the details of the each project (linked to `tblJobs`).  This form has two subforms:

1. `frmJobRolesSubform` details who's working on the project in what role ( and, notably, their sale rate.
2. `frmJobProcessesSubform` details the tasks, who's allocated to which task and the estimated number of hours to complete.

Both subforms link to their own tables (`tblJobs_Roles` and `tblJobs_Processes` respectively).

`frmJobProcessesSubform` obtains the people working on the project and their roles from `frmJobRolesSubform` so the manager can allocate a person to a task on `frmJobProcessesSubform`.  This is done via a combobox: `cboRole`.

So far, so good.

I'm needing to obtain the sale rate of the person working on the given task so that I can calculate the cost of the task.  Specifically, I'd like a field on the subform to calculate the cost of the task and then store it in `tblJobs_Processes`.

**My Attempts**

I've attempted to build a query (`qryProcessCost`) that calls `cboRole`, either as an expression in the Field cell or in the Criteria cell (`[Forms]![frmJobsProcessesSubform]![cboRole]`).

I'm aware this can't successfully when the form isn't active, but I'm getting Access' request for input for `[Forms]![frmJobsProcessesSubform]![cboRole]` when selecting from the subform.  The query runs successfully when example values are hardcoded into the query.  The query should, obviously, only return a single value.

I've tried setting the ControlSource of a textbox to `[qryProcessCost]![dblProcessCost]` (where `dblProcessCost` is the calculated field), but this can't then write to the table (as far as I can deduce).  Also, I get a `#Name?` error in the cell and I can't seem to get to the bottom of that.

I've tried setting the RecordSource property of a combobox to `SELECT [qryProcessCost]![dblProcessCost] FROM [qryProcessCost]`, and the ControlSource to the relevant field of the table.  While this would be a clunky solution, it actually doesn't work anyway as it fails to pick up the value of `[Forms]![frmJobsProcessesSubform]![cboRole]`.

I've tried using an intermediate textbox to determine what value `cboRole` is passing, and I'm happy with that - the primary key of the role assigned in `frmJobsRolesSubform`.

**The Question:**

I'm guessing that I'm probably going to have to resort to VBA at this point to get what I want but I'm unfamiliar with the Access VBA structures (though I've used Excel VBA a fair bit).

Anyone got any ideas, hints, suggestions or pointers?

Cheers in advance,

Aaron

Comment: The problem seems to be how you are referencing your subform in the query. Try something along the lines of: Forms!frmJobDetails.frmjobsProcessessSubform.form!cboRole   check this link for reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/113352

Comment: Thanks Gene, that got me part way to solving it but I still couldn't get it to do what I wanted.  I managed to solve the problem by using a DLookUp in a macro:
`SetTempVar
     Name      tempCostRate
     Expression =DLookUp("[dblCostRate]","[tblJobs_Roles]","[pkJobs_RoleID]="[cboRole])*[txtBudgetHours]

SetProperty
   Control Name  txtBudgetCost
   Property          Value
   Value               =[TempVars]![tempCostRate]`

Thanks for your pointer and the link, I'd forgotten that it'd need to reference subforms like that.  Aaron

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar problem, I've posted my complete solution below:

I implemented Gene's correction to my references, which provided something, but the query wouldn't update when the fields on the form were changed.  As I noted in the question, I also really wanted it to be a text box rather than a combo box for usability reasons but wasn't sure how to have a Record Source and Control Source for a text box.

I ended up going round in circles, via VBA and macros and several types of error and happened upon a suggestion to use a `DLookUp` [here](http://www.developerteacher.com/msdn/set-tempvar-to-query-value-144344).  I hadn't been able to get them to work for this particular problem before, but I managed to make it work this time.  Specifically, I put the `DLookUp` in the following macro:

```
SetProperty
   Control Name  txtBudgetCost
   Property      Value
   Value         =DLookUp("[dblCostRate]","[tblJobs_Roles]","[pkJobs_RoleID]="[cboRole])*[txtBudg‌​etHours]
```

This macro was used for the `After Update` event of the relevant fields on the subform.

Setting the value property of a field to a `DLookUp` meant that I could set the Control Source property of a the text box `txtBudgetCost` to the relevant field in the table, to obtain the desired behaviour.

Both `cboRole` and `txtBudgetHours` are fields on the same subform as the field `txtBudgetCost`.

The only problem with this solution is that, when the subform is viewed in the Datasheet view, a `#Name?` error is given for the new record row.  I probably just need to enter some error handling somewhere, though I haven't given much thought for what it should be just yet.

Cheers,

Aaron